# how do define something in an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am relatively new to JavaScript, and am trying to store callbacks in an array. Here is what I mean:

```js
items = [
    "test" = async message => {
        let userCoins = editCurrency('fetch', message.guild.id, message.author.id);

        if (userCoins) {
            let cauculations = (parseInt(userCoins)+100);
            editCurrency('set', message.guild.id, message.author.id, cauculations)
        }
    },
]
```

What am I supposed to do? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: @Ivar Sorry.. I had troubles selecting the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Objects in place of Array, if you need to give a name to function.

```
var callbacks: {
    "name": function(){},
    "another":function(){}
}
```

If Array is required, then can push objects in array.

```
var callbacks: [
    {"name": function(){}},
    {"another":function(){}}
]
```

Following may not be recommended but can also be done:

```
var callBacks = []
callBacks["name"] = function(){}
```

There is difference if you declare `var callBacks = {}` and `var callBacks = []` as mentioned in below:

[image: Difference between array and object declaration]

Comment: In the bottom example shouldn't it say ```var callbacks = {}``` instead of ```var callbacks = []```?

Comment: @MilanLakhani the point @Vishnu is trying to make is that it's _possible_ to do that, not that it's a good idea. Using `{}` as you suggest would indeed be a lot _better_.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't realise you could do that and it would work, looks strange

Comment: @MilanLakhani I have added an image comparing both declaration. It matters if you declare as array or object. Choice needs to be according to requirement

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays are used to store multiple values in a single variable.

Syntax:
const array_name = [item1, item2, ...];

Example :
const cars = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];

You access an array element by referring to the index number:
const cars = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];

let x = cars[0];    // x = "abc"

Comment: Hi Parmar, welcome to SO :) Chiming in to report that I think this is knowledge known by the author; when trying to answer a question, also try to see if the user made any errors; e.g. tried to use an object, not an array, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays in JavaScript are **not** associative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) - you are looking for an object instead, which can have string keys. As for the syntax, make sure that you are mixing up the operators.

```js
const items = {
    "test": async (message) => {
        // your callback
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a huge misunderstanding.

**TLDR: Use an object, not an array:**

```js
items = {
  "test": (async message) => {/* Your code here */}  
}
```

**Longer answer:**

An array only contains a list of values. There is no way to reference an item by its name.

If you really want an array, you could do this:

```js
items = [
  ((async message) => {/* Your code here */})
]
```

And then refer to the callback as `items[0]`